# Facing Device & Network Abuse Policy Violation for one of my apps

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

I am facing a Device & Network Abuse policy violation for one of my applications on Google Play Store. I went through other threads and I am not using Huawei SDK in my code. I do not have youtube video or any other external website that is being linked to my application which has any ads.I do not have YouTube API or any other random API from the internet. I am using SDKs from official sources of Google, Facebook, Amplitude, Applovin.

Any idea how can I go about troubleshooting it?